# Bash script doesn't launch with systemd

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to launch a simple bash script called `script-startup.sh` when my raspberry Pi boots, using systemd. This script only contains some basic actions on files (copying, moving, executing binaries) and calls make as well to compile bits of codes.

I created a new file with path `/etc/systemd/system/baymabx.service` :

```
[Unit]
Description=Baymabx
After=pm2-pi

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/Desktop/baymabx/script-startup.sh
```

Launching `/home/pi/Desktop/baymabx/script-startup.sh` in the terminal works as it is intended to be. Also, `pm2-pi.service` is pm2 starting my backend server, that I need before using my script.

However, after doing `systemctl start baymabx` and `systemctl status baymabx`, I get :

```
● baymabx.service - Baymabx
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/baymabx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-12-11 01:34:06 CET; 3min 2s ago
  Process: 359 ExecStart=/home/pi/Desktop/baymabx/script-startup.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 359 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Dec 11 01:34:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Baymabx.
Dec 11 01:34:06 raspberrypi systemd[359]: baymabx.service: Failed to execute command: Exec format error
Dec 11 01:34:06 raspberrypi systemd[359]: baymabx.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/pi/Desktop/baymabx/script-startup.sh: Exec format error
Dec 11 01:34:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: baymabx.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Dec 11 01:34:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: baymabx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Anyone know how I can get it to work ?

Comment: Do you have a #!/bin/bash at the top of script-startup.sh?

Comment: No I dont @RamanSailopal, what does it do exactly ?

Comment: It will inform systemd that the script needs to run in a bash shell

Comment: try `sudo chmod u+x <script_name>`  and then run it.